# DataGridViewComboBoxCell setting value manually, value not valid

Tags: c#, datagridview

here is my code:

```
        private class Person
        {
            private string myName;
            private int myValue;

            public Person(string name, int value)
            {
                myName = name; 
                myValue = value;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return myName;
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get { return myName; }
                set { myName = value; }
            }

            public int Value
            {
                get { return myValue; }
                set { myValue = value; }
            }
        }
```

I use it to fill a DataGridViewComboBoxCell like this:

```
myDataGridViewComboBoxCell.ValueMember = "Value";
myDataGridViewComboBoxCell.DisplayMember = "Name";
myDataGridViewComboBoxCell.Items.Add(new Person("blabla", someNumber));
```

all I want to do now is to select a person:

```
myDataGridViewComboBoxCell.Value = someNumber;
```

but keep getting "value is not valid"-error. Any Idea why?
When I select an Item in my program I can see the right Value (someNumber) so Display and ValueMember are set correctly...

Answer (score 11):

Rather than adding to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items`, you'll need to set `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource` to a List of Person, and set `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(Person)`.

Should do it. Although given it's been two months since you asked this, your problem may have lost it's sense of urgency.

Comment: I couldn't see the property `ValueType` on `DataGridView`. Did you mean `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` ?

Comment: Yes, it is on `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue.  I temporarily solved it in quite a dirty way.

The Value property of a DataGridViewComboBoxCell MUST be one of the values contained in the Items property (or bound DataSource)

The problem was that, for I dunno which reason, the cell's Items list (or its DataSource when I tried not entering Items manually) was cleared out as soon as the execution entered the `DataGridView.CellFormatting`  event handler for that Cell.

My dirty fix was to handle the `DataGridView.DataError` event and fill (again) the DataGridViewComboBoxCell.Items at that point.

```
Private Sub myDataGridView_DataError(ByVal sender As System.Object, _ 
                ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) _
                Handles dgvServicesToTransfer.DataError

        'Dirty Fix 
        If e.ColumnIndex = myComboBoxColumn.Index Then
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgvServicesToTransfer.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            ' Fill in your DataGridViewComboBoxCell's Items here:
            ' ...
            ' ...
            If allWentWell Then
                ' Cancel the exception
                e.ThrowException = False
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

PS: Sorry for the VB.Net answer, if you have problems "translating" it just ask.

Comment: This got me as well. I had the display and value member both set along with valuetype but still had issues. Finding out the value didn't exist in the current dropdown helped me find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. As strange as it sounds, I solved it by storing adding only strings to DataGridViewComboBoxCell.Items. Adding objects (with ToString() nicely implemented etc) caused these "Data Error" issues, but adding strings worked fine.

Answer (score -5):

Try To use enum for your persons name

```
enum person
{ 
 John,
 Andy,
 Sepehr
};
```

use this enum to add name to you combobox

```
myDataGridViewComboBoxCell.Items.Add ( person.andy.tostring(),number );
```

now when you want to set the vale use enum again. tyhis will fix your problem.

```
myDataGridViewComboBoxCell.Value = person.Andy.ToString() ;
```

Remembere to use --> `ToString()`  ! 
Worked for me ! :)

Comment: Enuming names? That makes your system very inflexible, what happens when a new person is joins, you'd have to recompile the code.

Comment: Using an enum for person names may be the worst advice I've ever seen on StackOverflow.