# Error: "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid." DataSource is list of basic type

Tags: c#, datagridview

I couldn't find a question on SO that *exactly* matched my problem.

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/654829/99640) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2753687/99640), I'm setting the `DataSource` on a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to a list of things. In my case the things are simple types like doubles and ints, so the answers talking about ValueMembers and DisplayMembers don't do me a lot of good. When the user selects a value I get the dreaded "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid" error.

I could swallow the error with an empty dataGridView_DataError handler, but that is obviously a bad way to go.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/datagridviewcomboboxcell-value-not-79018.aspx). It's also mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3139562/99640) to the second link in my question. When setting the `DataSource` to a list of anything that's not a string, set the `ValueType` of the column to `typeof(<your data type>)`

```
        IList<double> kvChoices;
        // Populate kvChoices...
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn kvCol =
            dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
        kvCol.DataSource = kvChoices;
        kvCol.ValueType = typeof(double);
```

Comment: Note:  I generally configure my grids at design time.  The ValueType property is not available at design time so I put the the following code in my Form_Load routine:     gridSequences.Columns[Year.Name].ValueType = typeof(Int32)

Answer (score 0):

This is finicky about sub-types. I still got the error when the ValueType was Int, but the DataSource contained a SQLServer SMALLINT (which a Visual Studio 2010 Quick-Watch on the DataSource said *was* an Int32 !). Changing the DB column from SMALLINT -> INT fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the value my datasource was returning was not available in the combobox.... my combo had value 1, 2 and 3... but datasource wanted 4.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same type of issue and figured I would answer what I did to correct this issue.

```cs
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
//Populate list with data

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn c1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
c1.ValueType = typeof(int);

c1.DataSource = myList;

dataGridView.Columns.Add(c1);
```

I hope I can help someone who still has this issue.