# get data from database to combobox in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I get the value in database to combobox in datagridview?
[image: error]

I have an error like this.
[image: error]

And this is my code:

```
dt.Columns.Clear();
        dgvMedExList.Refresh();
        dt.Columns.Add("MedExamID", typeof(Int32));
        dt.Columns.Add("MedExStatusID", typeof(Int32));
        dt.Columns.Add("MedExStatusDesc", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("MedExDefault", typeof(Boolean));
        bsMedExID.DataSource = dt;
        dgvMedExList.DataSource = bsMedExID;
```

Any help guys.

Comment: 1. Consider refactor the variable names; 2. Do you want dynamic or static columns? 3. Do you need certain cell types other than text?

Comment: Try this solution you may get your [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461885/error-datagridviewcomboboxcell-value-is-not-valid-datasource-is-list-of-basi)