# Datagridview combobox column does not fill values

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have problem with datagridview not filling combobox columns with values from database on only one column, other works perfectly. 
This is how I fill the table and then change the textbox columns with combobox columns.

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
a.Fill(t);
c.Close();
rootDataView.DataSource = CheckColumns(t);
foreach (primaryKey klic in pKeys)
{
     if (comboException.Contains(klic.FKColumn))
         {
             continue;
         }
     int indexOfpKeyCol = rootDataView.Columns.IndexOf(rootDataView.Columns[klic.FKColumn]);
     rootDataView.Columns.Remove(klic.FKColumn);
     DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
     cbColumn.Name = klic.FKColumn;
     cbColumn.DataPropertyName = klic.FKColumn;
     cbColumn.Items.Add("");
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select "+ klic.PKColumn +" from "+ klic.PKTable, c);
     c.Open();
     using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
              {
                 while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            cbColumn.Items.Add(reader[klic.PKColumn].ToString());
                        }
              }
      c.Close();
      rootDataView.Columns.Insert(indexOfpKeyCol, cbColumn);
}
rootDataView.Refresh();
```

I use same exact code for 10 other tables and none has problem with it, except this one.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[curveRate](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[workStatus] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[goal] [float] NOT NULL,
[timeFrom] [datetime] NULL,
[timeTo] [datetime] NULL,
[costCenter] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_curveRate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Foreign keys are on workStatus and costCenter. The one not working is workStatus, which is weird, because I use workStatus in other tables and it works. I am 100% sure that data types are both nvarchar(50) and they match.

When I debug it step by step, I am getting error for every row

> DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

After the DGV is loaded, comboboxes from costCenter column are filled, but workStatus is not. Is this failure of my code or database design ?

Comment: The error bc the type, you get that the value is not valid

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753687/datagridviewcomboboxcell-setting-value-manually-value-not-valid/3139562#3139562).